# How to store .csv data and calculate average value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, average, standard-deviation

Can someone help me to understand how I can save in matlab a group of .csv files, select only the columns in which I am interested and get as output a final file in which I have the average value of the y columns and standard deviation of y axes? I am not so good in matlab and so I kindly ask if someone to help me to solve this question.

Here what I tried to do till now:

```
     clear all;
clc;
which_column = 5; 
dirstats = dir('*.csv');
col3Complete=0;
col4Complete=0;
for K = 1:length(dirstats)

   [num,txt,raw] = xlsread(dirstats(K).name);
   col3=num(:,3);
   col4=num(:,4);
   col3Complete=[col3Complete;col3];
   col4Complete=[col4Complete;col4];
   avgVal(K)=mean(col4(:));
end
col3Complete(1)=[];
col4Complete(1)=[];
%columnavg = mean(col4Complete);
%columnstd = std(col4Complete);
% xvals = 1 : size(columnavg,1);
% plot(xvals, columnavg, 'b-', xvals, columnavg-columnstd, 'r--', xvals, columnavg+columstd, 'r--');

B = reshape(col4Complete,[5000,K]);
m=mean(B,2);
C = reshape (col4Complete,[5000,K]);
S=std(C,0,2);
```

Now I know that I should compute mean and stdeviation inside for loop, using `mean()`function, but I am not sure how I can use it.

Comment: why are you using `xlsread` for csv files? Second: initialise `col3Complete=[]`, then you do not have to clear the first entry after your loop.

Comment: Ok, now the code I modified it is working. I need only understand how I can calculate the standard deviation.

Comment: The same way you calculate the `mean` inside the loop, just use `std(col4(:))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  which_column = 5; 
  dirstats = dir('*.csv');
  col3Complete=[]; % Initialise as empty matrix
  col4Complete=[];
  avgVal = zeros(length(dirstats),2); % initialise as columnvector
  for K = 1:length(dirstats)

     [num,txt,raw] = xlsread(dirstats(K).name);
     col3=num(:,3);
     col4=num(:,4);
     col3Complete=[col3Complete;col3];
     col4Complete=[col4Complete;col4];
     avgVal(K,1)=mean(col4(:)); % 1st column contains mean
     avgVal(K,2)=std(col4(:)); % 2nd column contains standard deviation
  end
  %columnavg = mean(col4Complete);
  %columnstd = std(col4Complete);
  % xvals = 1 : size(columnavg,1);
  % plot(xvals, columnavg, 'b-', xvals, columnavg-columnstd, 'r--', xvals, columnavg+columstd, 'r--');

  B = reshape(col4Complete,[5000,K]);
  meanVals=mean(B,2);
```

I didn't change much, just initialised your arrays as empty arrays so you do not have to delete the first entry later on and made `avgVal` a column vector with the mean in column 1 and the standard deviation in column 1. You can of course add two columns if you want to collect those statistics for your 3rd column in the csv as well.

As a side note: `xlsread` is rather heavy for reading files, since Excel is horribly inefficient. If you want to read a structured file such as a csv, it's faster to use `importdata`.

Create some random matrix to store in a file with header:

```
A = rand(1e3,5);
out = fopen('output.csv','w');
fprintf(out,['ColumnA', '\t', 'ColumnB', '\t', 'ColumnC',  '\t', 'ColumnD',  '\t', 'ColumnE','\n']);
fclose(out);
dlmwrite('output.csv', A, 'delimiter','\t','-append');
```

Load it using `csvread`:

```
data = csvread('output.csv',1);
```

`data` now contains your five columns, without any headers.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can use importdata just changing xlsread, in the same line? It is right ?

Comment: not exactly. I do not have your csv files, but in general `importdata` gives you two things in a structure, let me add an example in the answer

Comment: How I can let you add the example  ? Anyway today running the code I get this error: Attempted to access num(:,3); index out of bounds because size(num)=[0,0].

Error in csvBatchRead (line 10)
   col3=num(:,3);

Comment: The example is in my answer, it's a proper place for it there. About the error: I'm not sure since I don't have your file, I suggest you read the docs on [`csvread`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html), which is a wrapper for [`dlmread`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html), which you can try as well. Hope something in there can help you!

Comment: Now it works, thanks. My basic error was that I didn't delete an old file inside the folder so I didn't process properly my data.

I have a second problem. How I can copy this data in an excel file properly? I used the function xlswrite but maybe something is wrong. If I write

xlswrite('file1.xlsx', m), 
for exemple, I am not able to see the file created inside the folder.

Comment: Do **not** ask 'little' things after a correct answer to the initial question has been provided. Please ask a new question with the new problem and leave this one as being complete and correct.